# Pacemaker lvm cluster

Tags: lvm, pacemaker

I have added disks to the cluster nodes through the "iscsid target" server. Those disks are visible with "lsblk". ( /dev/sdb) . But when you want to create "vg" and "lv" on the disks, it is not possible.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKbdD.png)

What form should this process take on 'node' - 1 if "vg" and "lv" are created, should I do this on the second "node"?

Answer (score 0):

You need first to "prepare" this disk for LVM:

```
pvcreate /dev/sdb
```

and then add to VG

```
vgcreate clustervg /dev/sdb
```